# Why does Mathematica use a dashed line for a contour line with this specific value?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to draw the contour lines of the following function, but I don't understand why the contour lines with value 0.5 and -0.5 are shown in dashed lines.

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

```
ContourPlot[{x*y/(x^2 + y^2) == 0.5, x*y/(x^2 + y^2) == -0.5, x*y/(x^2 + y^2) == -0.2}, {x, -2,2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Result from Mathematica]

Comment: Note that $\frac{x y}{x^2+y^2}=\pm 0.5$ is equivalent to $(x\pm y)^2=0$, so those contours are zero-touching, not zero-crossing. Further discussion is in the referenced duplicate.

Comment: In this case there's a simple workaround that I don't see mentioned in the duplicate.  Try  `ContourPlot[x*y/(x^2 + y^2) == 1/2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> #] & /@ {MachinePrecision, 10}`

Comment: @JasonB. Many thanks. What's the solution when x*y/(x^2+y^2)==-1/2?

Comment: @DavidR - `Plot[-x, {x,-2,2}]`?  Sorry, I can't seem to get that one to work as easily (try setting the `WorkingPrecision` to `Infinity` for amusement).  This seems to work, but it's a hack  `ContourPlot[x*y/(x^2 + y^2) == -.499999, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks a lot.